# Cross thread operation not valid when use backgroundworker in c#

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, backgroundworker

```
  private bool ImportData()
        {   
            bool result = false;
         try
            {

                      intdevid = int.Parse(cmbDeviceName.SelectedValue.ToString());
                         FetchDevicedata(intdevid);


                    //FTPTCompletedBatchTransfer();
                    FetchMaxReportId();

                    GetFTPFile(strDeviceIP, strDeviceUsername, strDevicePwd, strDevicePath + "//RunningBatch//RunningBatch.db", "RunningBatch.db"); // Copy RunningBatch.db to Debug Folder from Remote 
                    LoadRunningData(); // Get Running Data in dataset from running.db
                    if (DecodeBatchData_R() == false)
                    {

                        MessageBox.Show("Running Batch Data Not Found");


                    }// save in batch master and row data table

                    GetFTPFile(strDeviceIP, strDeviceUsername, strDevicePwd, strDevicePath + "//CompletedBatch//CompletedBatch.db", "CompletedBatch.db");
                    LoadCompletedData();
                    if (DecodeBatchData() == false)
                    {

                        MessageBox.Show("Completed Batch Data not found");

                    }
                    result = true;

                }



            catch (Exception ex)\\here error:Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'cmbDeviceName' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on.
            {
                clsLogs.LogError("Error: " + ex.Message + this.Name + " || ImportData");
                result = false;

            }



            return result;
        }
    private void btnimport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         //////////////////copy checkweigher .db to database folder
        dsCheckRptId = new DataSet();
        ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        if (cmbDeviceName.Text.ToString().Trim() == "--Select--")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please Select Proper Device");
            cmbDeviceName.Focus();
            return;
        }
        var deviceId = (int)cmbDeviceName.SelectedValue;
        bgw.RunWorkerAsync(deviceId);
        progressBar1.Visible = true;
        label2.Visible = true;



    }
    void bgw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {

        for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++)
        {
            var deviceId = (int)e.Argument;
            e.Result = ImportData();
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
            bgw.ReportProgress(i);

        }
    } 

    void bgw_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
        label2.Text = String.Format("Progress: {0} %", e.ProgressPercentage);
    }

    void bgw_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        var result = (bool)e.Result;
        if (cmbDeviceName.SelectedValue != null && cmbDeviceName.SelectedValue.ToString().Trim() != "0" && cmbDeviceName.SelectedValue.ToString().Trim() != "System.Data.DataRowView" && cmbDeviceName.SelectedValue.ToString().Trim() != "")

          if (result)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Data Import Completed Successfully for " + strDevicename);
            clsLogs.LogEvent(3, "Data Import Completed Successfully for " + strDevicename);
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Data Import Fail For " + strDevicename);
            clsLogs.LogEvent(3, "Data Import Fail for " + strDevicename);
        }    
        progressBar1.Visible = false;
        label2.Visible = false;
    }
```

;When I run this background worker coding, there's an error stating "Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'cmbDeviceName' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on. ."

How do I solve this problem guys?

Comment: Please make more effort to format your code - the indentation is all over the place. Look at your question before you post it, and ask yourself whether that's what you'd want to see if you were thinking of answering a question.

Answer (score 1):

WinForms controls are not thread safe, thus cross-thread operations on controls are not valid. You can access controls only from thread which created those controls. In your code you are accessing `cmbDeviceName` combobox from background thread. Best option to solve this is passing `intdevid` as `RunWorkerAsync` argument:

```
// executed on main thread
var deviceId = (int)cmbDeviceName.SelectedValue;
backgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync(deviceId);
```

And get this argument in your `DoWork` handler:

```
private void backgroundWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
   // executed on background thread
   var deviceId = (int)e.Argument;

   // ...
}
```

Suggested reading: [Safe, Simple Multithreading in Windows Forms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms951089.aspx)